# We haven't spoken - informal email

Tags: word-choice, word-request, vocabulary

Is the following sentence a good way to start an informal email?

Hi Jo,

How are you? **We haven't spoken to each other** for almost two months.

Is "**I haven't heard from you** for almost two months" better?

Have you got better options?

Comment: Questions like 'Is this sentence correct?' are off-topic - but if you usually communicate with Jo by email, that isn't 'speaking'. I would suggest "We haven't been in touch" rather than "I haven't heard from you", which  sounds like a reproach .

Comment: Thanks for your advice Kate. So, should the sentence be: - We haven't been in touch for almost two months OR We haven't been in touch with each other for almost two months? Thanks.

Comment: Either would do.